# How do I make my image sprites sit beside together?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a footer with social media icons. However, I don't know how to make the icons sit beside each other. They're just in the side and vertically aligned (idek how to align it in the center). I want them icons in the icons in the center and side-by-side.

HTML :

```html
<div class="footer1">
    <div class="fb"><a href="#"></div>
    <div class="ig"></div>
    <div class="yt"></div>
    <div class="twt"></div>
    <div class="pin"></div> 
</div>
```

CSS :

```css
.fb {
        background: url('../images/sites.png') no-repeat -79px -109px;
        width: 302px;
        height: 302px;
    }

    .ig {
        background: url('../images/sites.png') no-repeat -459px -110px;
        width: 307px;
        height: 307px;
    }

    .yt {
        background: url('../images/sites.png') no-repeat -852px -115px;
        width: 299px;
        height: 299px;
    }

    .twt {
        background: url('../images/sites.png') no-repeat -1244px -114px;
        width: 295px;
        height: 293px;
    }

    .pin {
        background: url('../images/sites.png') no-repeat -1632px -112px;
        width: 293px;
        height: 293px;
    }
```

Comment: Use `display: flex,` and **flex items** (social media icons) should be in a **flex container.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this. [Flexboxes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) are really handy.

```
<html>
    <style>
    .footer {
        display: flex;
        gap: 20px; /* Here you can specify a gap between the child elements*/
    }

    .footer img {
        width: 30px;
    }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="footer">
            <img src="../images/someicon1.png"></img>
            <img src="../images/someicon2.png"></img>
            <img src="../images/someicon3.png"></img>
            <img src="../images/someicon4.png"></img>
            <img src="../images/someicon5.png"></img>
        <div>
    </body>
</html>
```